# adding density on axes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I was doing some pretty plots with these density bars on the axes,
but since there I've lost the code and the ability to reproduce the bars.

[image]

It would be wonderful if someone could point me to the right command

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SE. For future questions, please include a minimal, reproducible example that ppl trying to help can run on their side to reproduce the issue and/or to answer your question. This will increase the chances of you getting a proper answer quickly. Thanks!

Comment: I really don't understand what am i doing wrong. I can't attach a reproducible example, since i am trying to relroduce the example... there was a picture i attached. Is there any problem with the way i attached it?Thanks to Maurits who was so kind to give the right and easy answer.

Comment: What I meant was including the sample data you want to plot, plus the code you use to generate the plot (in this case the scatter plot, without the `geom_rug`), Maurits had to do it himself and use `mtcars`, but in the future please include your own sample data as this will speed things up for everybody :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `geom_rug`; here is an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = as.factor(am))) + geom_point() + geom_rug()
```

[image]